# Insert/Update Multiple Rows in MySQL with PHP and Jquery

Tags: php, mysql, insert

I have a table that is populated by a MS Sql query from one database that gives me values from patient visits and the revenue generated from those visits.  I have a checkbox that populates the corresponding text input box showing that visit was paid for.  My question is how can I add/update multiple rows using MySQL and PHP.  There are two different databases (MySQL and MS SQL).

The HTML table.

```
<table>
<thead>
<tr>
<th>First Name / Last Name</th>
<th>Alias</th>
<th>Status</th>
<th class="amountDue">$00,000.00</th>
<th colspan="2" class="appliedAmount">$00,000.00<?th>
<th class="variance">$00,000.00</th>
<th>Complete</th>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><td>
<td><td>
<td><?php echo $patRow['VisitNum']; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $patRow['VisitName']; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $patRow['AmountDue']; ?></td>
<td><input type="checkbox"></td>
<td><input type="text" name="Amount[]"></td>
<!-- Invoice Populated from Database --!>
<td><select class="invoiceNumber">
    <option>4565</option>
    </select>
</tr>

</tr>
</table>
```

Now the PHP.

```
<?php
require('../assets/dbconnect.php');
$size_array = count($_POST['Amount']);
for ($i=0; $i<$size_array; $i++){
$query = 'INSERT INTO webportal.test (id, PSID, SysPatVisitID, AmountDue, Amount, InvoiceNum)'.
" VALUES ('', '".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['PSID'][$i])."', 
'".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['SysPatVisitID'][$i])."'', 
'".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['AmountDue'][$i])."'', 
'".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['Amount'][$i])."'', 
'".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['InvoiceNum'][$i])."')
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE content=VALUES(
'".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['AmountDue'][$i])."'',
'".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['Amount'][$i])."'',
'".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['InvoiceNum'][$i])."''
";

$result = mysql_query($query) or die (mysql_error());
}
```

So this is what I have so far and when I try to insert into my database it only inserts the first record and I get an error.  Eventually I want to pass these variables with Jquery, but I just need to get the PHP working first.

Comment: @RogerLindsjö - Its returning a mysql id error, but when I check my database it inserts just the first row of infromation so this leads me to believe that there is something wrong with my insert statement for the ID - It is not auto incrementing on the insert/update.

Comment: Please stop using the outdated `mysql_*` functions ans learn how to use [PDO](http://php.net/PDO) and prepared statements.

Answer (score 0):

```
$query = 'INSERT INTO webportal.test (PSID, SysPatVisitID, AmountDue, Amount, InvoiceNum)'.
" VALUES ('".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['PSID'][$i])."', 
'".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['SysPatVisitID'][$i])."', 
'".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['AmountDue'][$i])."', 
'".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['Amount'][$i])."', 
'".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['InvoiceNum'][$i]).")
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE content=VALUES(
'".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['AmountDue'][$i])."',
'".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['Amount'][$i])."',
'".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['InvoiceNum'][$i])."'
";
```

- You're not matching your `'`s correctly. `'". <stuff> ."''`. You only need one closing tick.
- You forgot your closing bracket for `VALUES`.
- If you wish for your `id` to be auto incremented by the DBMS, don't include it in your query at all.

Also, error messages exist for a reason. Learning to understanding them will greatly increase your debugging capabilities. If you don't understand the error, just look it up on [MySQL.com](http://mysql.com).